# Android-GridView, can not fix size of convertView to fit the screen

Tags: android, gridview

I have tried for 2 day, but I CAN NOT KNOW WHY my gridView can not display in full width,I tried, I tried, I tried...

My eyes are about to become eyes of devil. I have no time to try to fix it anymore. Please find me out of problem..

[image]

Here is my code:
Grid:

```
gridLightMaster.setAdapter(new LightImageGridAdater(getActivity()
                    .getApplicationContext(), listLights, display.getWidth(),
                    display.getHeight()));
```

Adapter:

```
import java.util.List;
import com.fptsoftware.iolaunchapp.LayoutDimmerLight;
import com.fptsoftware.iolaunchapp.Logger;
import com.fptsoftware.iolaunchapp.R;

public class LightImageGridAdater extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;
    List<EnLightItem> data;
    private int mWidth, mHeight;
    ViewHolder holder;

    public LightImageGridAdater(Context ctx, List<EnLightItem> data, int width,
            int height) {
        this.mContext = ctx;
        this.data = data;
        this.mWidth = width;
        this.mHeight = height;
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        ImageView img;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public EnLightItem getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return data.get(position);


    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @SuppressLint({ "InflateParams", "ViewHolder" })
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        Log.d("size parent:", "" + parent.getHeight() + "," + parent.getY());
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.item_light_horizontal_list1, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgLight1);

            holder.img.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = convertView.getLayoutParams();
         params.width = mWidth / 3;
        params.height = mHeight / 4;
        convertView.setLayoutParams(params);

        // GestureDetectorCoonvertView).gestureDetector = mDetector;
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Layout Grid:

```
     <GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridMasterLight"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:numColumns="3"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />
```

Layout to inflate :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/imgLight1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: @RemeesMSyde his `ImageView` should be this item...

Comment: Try imageview with android:layout_width="match_parent" may help you.

Comment: it still not working ....>.<